# Ограничить количество <select> option с помощью js

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как ограничить количество выпадающих категорий в списке select с помощью js или убрать последнюю категорию из списка.
С помощью $('select option[value=]').hide(); не получается. Сам код с шаблона модуля tpl opencart 2

```
    <select name="make_id" id="i-make" class="form-control">
        <option value="" selected="selected" onclick="selFunc(this)"><?php echo $made_title ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($car_makes as $car_make) {?>
        <option value="<?php echo $car_make['car_make_id']; ?>" <?php if ($car_make['car_make_id']==$car_make_id) { echo 'selected="selected"';} ;?>
        ><?php echo $car_make['b_name']; ?></option>
        <?php }?>
    </select>
```

Comment: `$('select').find('option:last').remove();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sel').find('option:last').remove();
  //или так $('#sel option:last').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Спасибо всё получилось!!!